# Referencing a variable showing 'local variable 'final_ans' referred before declaration'

Tags: python, python-3.x

This snippet of code below is giving 'local variable 'final_ans' referred before declaration'

```
def powerset(array):
    # Write your code here.

    def helper(arr, idx, temp=[]):
        if idx == len(arr):
            final_ans+=[temp]
            return
        helper(arr,idx+1, temp + [arr[idx]])
        helper(arr,idx+1, temp)
        return

    final_ans = []
    helper(array,0,[])
    return final_ans

print(powerset([1,2,3]))
```

whereas, this code snippet below is working without any error.

```
def powerset(array):
    # Write your code here.

    def helper(arr, idx, temp=[]):
        if idx == len(arr):
            final_ans.append(temp)
            return
        helper(arr,idx+1, temp + [arr[idx]])
        helper(arr,idx+1, temp)
        return

    final_ans = []
    helper(array,0,[])
    return final_ans

print(powerset([1,2,3]))
```

I understand that using `nonlocal` in the first snippet will make the code work. But I am failing to understand how is the scope changing by using `append` instead of `+=`.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. `append` instead of `+=` _isn't_ changing the scope, `nonlocal ` is

Comment: It's an interesting question, and the reason for this apparently strange behaviour is not simply a question of scope, but also a question of whether the nonlocal variable is being assigned to or not.

Comment: maybe write it without `final_ans` but use return to send it outside function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Append works, even without declaring final_ans as nonlocal, because it is a method call, NOT an assignment. Nonlocal variables cannot be ASSIGNED to unless they are first declared as nonlocal, but they CAN be referenced, for example on the RHS of an assignment.